# LAMP vs Windows Server 2008 scenario

Tags: linux, windows-server-2008, mysql, php, lamp

I see there is a lot of things online about this, but wanted an answer specific to this scenario. I can think of a few issues with this, but wanted to ask everyone to get the whole picture.

Can anyone think of possible pitfalls with having a LAMP development server and a windows IIS production servers. They will have the same version of MySQL and php.

Comment: For starters, your php.ini is likely going to be different.

Comment: Why would you want dev and production to be different OSes?

Comment: i dont want them to be different, but circumstances are that the production server will be windows server and iis (arggghh). Also, i'd like to setup a git repository for the site, and having the repository and the dev preview on a linux machine would be ideal.

Answer (score 2):

Having development and production be different is generally a very bad idea.

Sure, you can tell your developers to be aware, and they may even mostly will be.  But sooner or later you'll run into an issue and your only recourse will be to debug it in production, because development won't have the same problem.

Just because its the same major version of mysql/php, doesn't mean there can't be problems which will only reveal themselves on a single platform.

Now, if you have dev being what ever they want, then a test IIS server, then a production IIS server, you can avoid almost all of these problems.

I can't think of a compelling reason (saving a couple thousand on licensing costs for a test server isn't compelling; my troubleshooting time isn't free) to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I see no problems there, as long as the developers are aware of the windows vs. linux differences. Path separators / and \ come there to mind ...

Nevertheless I think that a last test will have to run on the IIS Server before going to production use.